# JS принудительно вызвать автозаполнение поля input

Tags: javascript, html

Каким образом средствами джаваскрипта можно вызвать автозаполнение в строке? Например заходим в поисковик яндекс и если нажать на инпут с вводом запроса для поиска нам вылезет автозаполнение снизу, как можно вызвать эту функцию в инпуте программно? Пробовал document.getElementsByName('text')[0].focus(); и click(); но это не сработало у меня

Comment: Для этого в HTML5 есть встроенный тег [datalist](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist)

Comment: Это зависит от реализации автозаполнения. То, что будет работать на яндексе, вполне может не работать на гугле. Уточните ваш вопрос - зачем вам это надо и что вы хотите с этим делать.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Хорошо тогда мне нужно именно для яндекса вызвать автозаполнение, просто другой вариант не подойдет для меня, мне нужно именно заставить яндекс показать это окошко с автозаполнением

Comment: Хорошо, теперь, где вы хотите это сделать? В браузерной консоли? Какой браузер? И зачем вам это надо?

Comment: Думаю любой парсер справится с таким....но вот проблема...у вас тег `js`...и как же вы хотите это сделать? Интересно, а как вы пробовали?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Я пишу гугл расширение чисто для себя для упрощения некоторых задач в браузере, и тут появилась идея для реализации которой мне нужно открыть сайт яндекс и вывести это автозаполнение для начала, я понимаю возможно существуют и другие способы это сделать без вызова автозаполнения но сейчас мне нужно именно вызвать автозаполнение у яндекса, у меня уже случались случаи когда нужно было сделать что то похожее но у меня не получалось, поэтому хочу посмотреть как это вообще возможно сейчас реализовать или нет

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Ну например я пробовал в гугл хроме в консоль (думаю не принципиально как я ввел js код на страницу но все же) ввести document.getElementsByName('text')[0].focus(); и document.getElementsByName('text')[0].click() что, в теории, должно сработать как нажатие пользователем по этому полю и вызову автозаполнения, но это не сработало, я пробовал и другие варианты из интернета но не найдя ответа пришел к вам

Comment: У меня получилось через следующий код `$0.__uniqMBEMListeners33351.focus[0]()`. Но, как видно из названия свойства `__uniqMBEMListeners33351` - оно генерируется автоматически и может меняться.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko А что такое $0? Это что то из jquery?

Comment: Нет, это из консоли гугл хрома. Можете заменит на `document.getElementById('text')`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Ага ну хорошо спасибо это уже хоть что то